# Pass a variable from controller to javascript in view

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, json, codeigniter

I'm trying to pass a variable from the controller to the view through JSON.
The data that I want to check is available but if I try to access it like "data.status" it comes back as undefined.

The code that I use in the controller is:

```
public function checkserie(){
    $data['status'] = 'success';
    $this->output->set_output(json_encode($data, JSON_PRETTY_PRINT));
}
```

And the code that I use in the view is:

```
$.post('<?php echo base_url("index.php/manageorderseries/checkserie")?>', { name: $("#seriename").val()}).done(function(data) {
        alert(data.status);
});
```

I also saw that when I replace "data.status" with just "data", I receive the following in my alert:

```
{status: "success"}
```

What did I miss to access the variable as "data.status"?

Thanks in advance !
Kind regards,

Jonas Vandevelde

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The response you are getting is JSON, so JS needs to parse that if you want to use it like an ordinary JS object.

You can use either [JSON.parse()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc836466(v=vs.85).aspx) or [$.parseJSON()](http://api.jquery.com/jquery.parsejson/) (since you already are using jQuery) to accomplish this.

```
$.post('<?php echo base_url("index.php/manageorderseries/checkserie")?>', { name: $("#seriename").val()}).done(function(data) {
    var dataObj = JSON.parse(data);
    alert(dataObj.status);
});
```